# Changing TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso output with Android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, geolocation, android-emulator

I'm making an app that uses users location to determine what data to show the user. I'm using  TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso(NOT the sim version) to determine the location and it's working like a charm. Is there anyway that i can test this further by changing a setting in the emulator settings so i can make it believe that the phone is in another country besides US(default).

At the moment TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso is outputting: "us"

NOTE: i know that getNetworkCountryIso has some drawbacks but thats for another discussion :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following command to change the value:

1. `adb shell`
2. `su`
3. `setprop gsm.operator.iso-country uk`
4. On some Emulator, you might need to restart it to have the impact.

See ScreenShot below:
[image: cmd]

On some emulators, the property name could be different.

You can find the property name as follows:

1. `adb shell`
2. `getprop`

It will give you data similar to following:

```
...
[dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold]: [500]
[dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file]: [/data/anr/traces.txt]
[dalvik.vm.usejit]: [true]
[dalvik.vm.usejitprofiles]: [true]
[debug.atrace.tags.enableflags]: [0]
[debug.force_rtl]: [0]
[dev.bootcomplete]: [1]
[drm.service.enabled]: [true]
[gsm.current.phone-type]: [1]
[gsm.defaultpdpcontext.active]: [true]
[gsm.network.type]: [LTE]
[gsm.nitz.time]: [1524141151210]
[gsm.operator.alpha]: [Android]
[gsm.operator.iso-country]: [us]
[gsm.operator.isroaming]: [false]
[gsm.operator.numeric]: [310260]
[gsm.sim.operator.alpha]: [Android]
[gsm.sim.operator.iso-country]: [us]
[gsm.sim.operator.numeric]: [310260]
[gsm.sim.state]: [READY]
[gsm.version.baseband]: [1.0.0.0]
[gsm.version.ril-impl]: [android reference-ril 1.0]
[hwservicemanager.ready]: [true]
[init.svc.adbd]: [running]
[init.svc.audio-hal-2-0]: [running]
[init.svc.audioserver]: [running]
[init.svc.bootanim]: [stopped]
[init.svc.camera-provider-2-4]: [running]
[init.svc.cameraserver]: [running]
...
```

Search for `iso-country` by copying the output in text file. Get the property name and use `setprop <property name> <new iso>`

You can also use `getProp` to verify whether the value has been changed.

Comment: I can getprop etc. but i get the message setprop: failed to set property 'gsm.operator.iso-country' to 'uk' when using setprop :(

Comment: did you enter `su` ? This error only comes if you don't give super user permission.

Comment: /system/bin/sh: su: not found

Comment: can you check your emulator is online? Just type `adb devices`

Comment: Do you have multiple emulator running?

Comment: For me it only happens if I don't use `su`. I have updated the answer with screen shot

Comment: i got su working with another emulator. i was using Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image but changed it to Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image and now su works :-)

Comment: Oh. Ok. That' new info for me. Doesn't happen on my Laptop. Does the command works?

Comment: Ye now adb is crashing like every 5sec...let me fix that and get back :D

Comment: @fayyaz OK :-D. I changed the ABI to x86 Google APIs when I faced the same issue while using armeabi0-v7a

Comment: Update from 2021: I had the same error (`/system/bin/sh: su: not found`) on emulators with Play Market installed. On emulator without Play Market all works like a charm.

Comment: `/system/bin/sh: su: inaccessible or not found` in my `API 32` emulator. `Failed to set property 'gsm.operator.iso-country' to 'uk'.
See dmesg for error reason. `